# Ultracapacitor doesn't charge

Tags: capacitor, charge, supercapacitor, capacitor-charging

I am concerned about an ultracapacitor (2.7v, 3000F) that I received today. I set my power supply to 2.5v with a current limit of 1A, then connected a diode to the positive lead such that current would only flow to charge the capacitor. I then connected the end of the diode to the positive terminal of the capacitor and ground from my PSU to the negative terminal of the capacitor.

However, only about 2mA was drawn. The diode I am using has a low diode drop (~0.3v), so I figured it should still charge the capacitor to around 2.2v. I then adjusted the voltage such that there would be 2.7v across the capacitor (~3.0v from the PSU), and it slightly increased the current drawn, but the change is negligible.

I can't see anything wrong with this charging setup, so is it likely that the capacitor is bad? Perhaps the polarity indicated on the capacitor is incorrect? Is reverse voltage harmful to ultracapacitors, meaning that I shouldn't check? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the datasheet of the ultracapacitor? Are you sure the capacitor was discharged before you connected? Also, what is the output voltage of the PSU when you first connect to the capacitor?

Comment: @ThePhoton unfortunately I can not find a datasheet for this capacitor. I suppose this is the price I pay for saving a few dollars by buying the cheap Chinese brand from ebay. [Here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item//32863920604.html) is the listing for it on aliexpress if it helps at all.

I am sure that the capacitor was discharged before connecting it to the power supply. I checked with my multimeter to find that it was charged to 11mV, so I shorted the terminals just in case.

The output voltage of the PSU was either 2.7v or 2.5v (I forget).

Comment: At 1 A, it should take ~2.25 hrs to charge the capacitor to 2.7 V. Are your sure your PSU didn't just shut down because it thought it was shorted?

Comment: A datasheet (or at least model number) for the PSU might help guess whether this could explain it.

Comment: @ThePhoton If I short my power supply, it will supply the max current set.

Comment: What happens when you take out the diode? You shouldn't need it. In the event of the PSU losing mains power it's output would be powered by the capacitor but at 2.5 V it is very unlikely to be damaged. Since \$ Q = CV \$ we get \$ V = \frac {Q}{C} \$ and differentiating we get \$ \frac {dV}{dt} = \frac {1}{C} \frac {dQ}{dt} 
 = \frac {I}{C} \$. With your 3000 F and 1 A you'll get \$ \frac {dV}{dt} = \frac {1}{3000} = 0.3 \ \text {mV/s} \$ if my calculation is correct.

Comment: @Transistor I tried without the diode and nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: This will take a few hours to charge up; have you given it that much time?

Comment: @Felthry I've been letting it charge for a while now, but shouldn't more current flow at first? Only 2mA out of my 1A limit flows and the current hasn't changed.

Comment: How are you measuring the current? If you're using a meter, are you using the right ports (voltage and current measurement often require different connections to the meter)? A photo of your setup could help. Or maybe the capacitor is just dead.

Comment: Put your multimeter across the capacitor while connected to the power-supply. Take a reading. Disconnect the capacitor and take another reading across the capacitor. They should be the same. If they're not the capacitor is faulty.

Comment: @ThePhoton I am definitely using the right ports on the multimeter.

Comment: @Transistor I left my multimeter connected and when I disconnected the positive lead from my power supply, the voltage dropped quickly at first but then slowed down after a couple seconds.

Comment: It looks like you've got a tiny capacitor in a big can. If the voltage drops that quickly with tha high impedance of a multimeter it is hopeless. Look for a refund.

Comment: If the capacitor is bad, get a refund -- there should be no charge.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik that's what I'm doing, but I wanted to make sure it was bad before I requested a refund.